# How to run a java program using apache ant and eclipse in windows 64 bit OS?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, apache, ant

Problem in running apache ant using java in eclipse on windows.
Can anyone suggest me how can I run an ant using eclipse in windows 64 bit operating system.
I found that there is no apache ant software for 64 bit os. Can anyone please let me know how?

can I run a program using apache ant using eclipse in windows 64 bit os?

Comment: is your eclipse 32-bit or 64-bit? if you use 32-bit eclipse (even in 64-bit windows), I don't see any reason why ant wouldn't behave as it normally does.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 64-bit version of ant because ant is written in java, thus it works on both 32 and 64 bit systems. It uses the JRE the JAVA_HOME environment variable points to (IIRC).

Check out the bin folder in your ant install, there are no binaries in there, only scripts to start java.

You have most likely a configuration problem with your windows environment or in eclipse itself.